# Create generic tuple with same class elements

Tags: java, generics, tuples, containers

I want to create a generic tuple with two values. For example a tuple with two strings or two integers etc. (Generic values). But it should not be able to mix both elements, for example a string with an integer (Like for example a hash map).

How can I create a type-same tuple? At the moment I use wildcard generics parameter for both elements in the tuple and of course that doesn't force a developer to use the same class type for both elements.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Main {
    class Element<T extends Comparable<?> & Serializable> {
        private final T element;

        public Element(T element) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        public String raw() {
            return element.toString();
        }
    }

    class Tuple<T extends Element<?>, U extends Element<?>> {
        private final Element<?> element1;
        private final Element<?> element2;

        public Tuple(Element<?> element1, Element<?> element2) {
            this.element1 = element1;
            this.element2 = element2;
        }

        public Element<?> getElement1() {
            return element1;
        }

        public Element<?> getElement2() {
            return element2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        Element<String> element1 = new Element<String>(new String("First tuple element"));
        Element<String> element2 = new Element<String>(new String("Second tuple element"));
        Element<Integer> wrongelement = new Element<Integer>(42); // <-- Should not be possible, but it is...
        Tuple<Element<String>, Element<String>> tuple = new Tuple<Element<String>, Element<String>>(element1, element2);

        // First tuple element
        System.out.println(tuple.getElement1().raw());

        // Second tuple element
        System.out.println(tuple.getElement2().raw());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use only one generic type in your `Tuple` class and have your element fields be of that generic type, not the super class (i.e. `T element1` and not `Element<?> element1`):

```
class Tuple<T extends Element<?>> {

    private final T element1;
    private final T element2;

    public Tuple(T element1, T element2) {
        this.element1 = element1;
        this.element2 = element2;
    }

    public T getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }

    public T getElement2() {
        return element2;
    }
}
```

And then you can simply instantiate it with one type as such:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    Element<String> element1 = new Element<String>(new String("First tuple element"));
    Element<String> element2 = new Element<String>(new String("Second tuple element"));

    Tuple<Element<String>> tuple = new Tuple<Element<String>>(element1, element2);

    // First tuple element
    System.out.println(tuple.getElement1().raw());

    // Second tuple element
    System.out.println(tuple.getElement2().raw());
}
```

Btw, you don't have to `new String` your strings, you can simply provide them as regular Strings:

```
Element<String> element1 = new Element<String>("First tuple element");
Element<String> element2 = new Element<String>("Second tuple element");
```

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea why I wasn't thinking about that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you simply want this:

```
class Tuple<T extends Comparable<?> & Serializable> {
    private final Element<T> element1;
    private final Element<T> element2;

    public Tuple(Element<T> element1, Element<T> element2) {
        this.element1 = element1;
        this.element2 = element2;
    }

    public Element<T> getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }

    public Element<T> getElement2() {
        return element2;
    }
}

public Main() {
    Element<String> element1 = new Element<>("First tuple element");
    Element<String> element2 = new Element<>("Second tuple element");
    Element<Integer> wrongelement = new Element<>(42);

    // compiles fine
    Tuple<String> tuple = new Tuple<>(element1, element2); 

    // doesn't compile
    Tuple<String> tuple = new Tuple<>(element1, wrongelement); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I accepted the other answer as solution because it was the first one. I also guess returning T is more generic and simplifies refactoring the code (In case you want to replace Element with AnotherElement). On the other hand, IDE support might be better for a written out return Element<T>.

Comment: The other answer looks wrong to me. It allows doing this, for example: `Tuple<Element<?>> tuple = new Tuple<Element<?>>(element1, wrongelement);`. You don't seem to want a Tuple parameterized with subclasses of Element. You seem to want a tuple containing two elements of the same generic type.

Answer (score 0):

In the interests of not reinventing the wheel, you might consider using an exsiting Tuple or Pair implementation. Apache's [commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library, for example, includes a [`Pair<R, L>`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) implementation which you could extend by an empty class which just ties the two generic type parameters to be the same...

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair

public class MyPair<T> extends Pair<T, T> { }
```

If you really want to keep your API, you could very simply implement the methods in terms of the Pair methods `left()` and `right()`.